# SQLAlchemy Inserting Parentheses in UNION ALL Causing SQL Syntax Errors in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I can't seem to get SQLAlchemy to generate proper SQL that satisfies SQLite.

SQLAlchmey query:

```
q = select([0]).union_all(select([0]).limit(30))
```

That produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT ? UNION ALL (SELECT 0 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?)
```

Which leads to:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error
```

The issues seems to be the `()` that SQLAlchemy adds after the `UNION ALL` clause.
Without the parentheses the query executes fine.

ie. the following SQL works without issue:

```
SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

Note:

- SQLAlchemy does not generate parentheses if no `LIMIT` clause is provided.
- I am using:

  - Python 3.8
  - SQLAlchemy v1.3.19
  - SQLite v3.31.1

Comment: I am able to reproduce your issue. You may want to open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues) to report it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I'll post a bug.

Comment: Related bug issue: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5564